# How do I make my repo appear on my Github Desktop (Github for Windows)?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I made a repo on my local hard drive and push it to github using CLI. It's up on Github now. But now I want it to also appear on my github desktop. The only option I see is 'clone' and 'save to my computer'. These options are meant to make a new directory inside my local hard drive and clone what's already on my github there, while I already have the original file on my hard drive. So, how do I make my repository appear on my Desktop without cloning?
Can someone help, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In yours desktop GitHub open "Add" (blue "plus" button on the top-left) and add yours local repo. Then in that repo's settings point it's "Remote" origin to yours github repo (url to `github.com/user/repo/repo.git` file) at server.

Comment: funnily enough I tried this yesterday and it didn't work. Today I added my local repo and it automatically detects its own remote repo. I have no idea why it didn't work yesterday. Still, thank you!

Comment: Maybe, something like hitting "Publish" or "Synk" was required. Anyway, I'm glad it worked, GitHub for Desktop still laks stability and usability, even if version is 3.0+ already %)